# add column name at the end of each value of a column pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df, something like this:

```
     date  col1    col2    col3        col4
0  4-4-22   cat  ginger  gentle      placed
1  4-4-22   dog  golden    wild  not placed
2  4-4-22  fish   black  domest  not placed
3  4-4-22   dog   brown  gentle      placed
```

For the list of names of the columns that I give, I want each value of those columns to have the column name added in brackets at the end. For eg.

```
lst = ['col2', 'col4']
```

Desired output:

```
     date  col1           col2    col3               col4
0  4-4-22   cat  ginger (col2)  gentle      placed (col4)
1  4-4-22   dog  golden (col2)    wild  not placed (col4)
2  4-4-22  fish   black (col2)  domest  not placed (col4)
3  4-4-22   dog   brown (col2)  gentle      placed (col4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) after ensuring that the columns are strings (with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)):

```
cols = ['col2', 'col4']

df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).add([f' ({c})' for c in cols])
```

Output:

```
     date  col1           col2    col3               col4
0  4-4-22   cat  ginger (col2)  gentle      placed (col4)
1  4-4-22   dog  golden (col2)    wild  not placed (col4)
2  4-4-22  fish   black (col2)  domest  not placed (col4)
3  4-4-22   dog   brown (col2)  gentle      placed (col4)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the *Series* attribute [`name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.name.html) :

> property Series.name : **Return the name of the Series**.

```
lista = ["col2", "col4"]
​
df[lista] = df[lista].apply(lambda x: x + f" ({x.name})")
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

     date  col1           col2    col3               col4
0  4-4-22   cat  ginger (col2)  gentle      placed (col4)
1  4-4-22   dog  golden (col2)    wild  not placed (col4)
2  4-4-22  fish   black (col2)  domest  not placed (col4)
3  4-4-22   dog   brown (col2)  gentle      placed (col4)
```